# Key error when printing a column in pandas dataframe but the column is printed

Tags: python, pandas

When I'm trying to print a column of a pandas DataFrame i recive a KeyError but in the console i see data of this column. After a couple of changes i noticed that when i call "print" before the for loop it works but putting it 1 line after the for loop it gives the error. Also i need to drop this column later in the for loop and it gives the same error

```
array_columns = ['Stochastic_RSI', 'MACD', 'BOLLINGER_BANDS']
    scaler = StandardScaler()

    for array_column in array_columns:
        not_array = dataframe[array_column].values
        column_array = np.array([i[1: -1].split(', ') for i in not_array]).astype(float).round(5)
        std_column = scaler.fit_transform(column_array)

        num = np.shape(std_column)[1]

        for n_column in range(num):
            print(dataframe[array_column])        # Error at this line
            print(dataframe.head(5).to_string())  # Still prints

            column_name = str(f'{array_column}_{n_column}')

            dataframe[column_name] = std_column[:, n_column]
            dataframe.drop(array_column, axis=1, inplace=True)

    return dataframe
```

The interesting part arrives when the print after the error still prints the data in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Directory", line 203, in <module>
    main()
File "D:\Directory", line 175, in main
    df = pre_process(df)
File "D:\Directory", line 72, in pre_process
    df = float_list_array(df)
File "D:\Directory", line 90, in float_list_array
    print(dataframe[array_column])
File "C:\Directory", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Directory", line 3623, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
    KeyError: 'Stochastic_RSI'
```

[image: ScreenShot of my code]

Comment: You drop "array_column" at the end of the inner for-loop although this loop may iterate multiple times for the same "array_column".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You drop `array_column` at the end of the inner for-loop although this loop may iterate multiple times for the same `array_column`.

Courtesy of [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher) in [a comment to the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859988/key-error-when-printing-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-but-the-column-is-printed/73860110#comment130418941_73859988).